# Determine if tautology, contingency or contradiction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to determine if the statement is a tautology, contradiction or contingency. Been at it for days but didn't get too far.

The original question is

$$\left((\lnot p\vee z)\wedge(p\vee q)\right)\rightarrow(z\vee q)$$

I got to here
$$\left((p\wedge\lnot z)\vee(\lnot p\wedge\lnot q)\right)\vee(z\vee q)$$

Any suggestions? Not allowed to use double distribution.

Can't use truth tables, just rules of logic.

Comment: Which rules exactly? Some sort of proof theory system (like natural deduction or sequent calculus)? Algebraic logic, using the laws of Boolean algebra? 
When I looked at it (I was trained in sequent calculus, so this is an outline of a sequent calculus argument), the first thing I did was to rewrite $\neg p \vee z$ as $p\to z$. Then I used a right weakening and to get $q\to z\vee q$ and modus ponens (together with another right weakening) to get $(p\wedge (p\to z))\to z\vee q$. From there, it was just a disjunction elimination, and a cut, to  get $((p\vee q)\wedge (\neg p\vee z))\to(z\vee q)$.

Comment: these rules https://www.scs.carleton.ca/sites/default/files/course_page/logic_1.pdf

also don't know what you mean by right weakening but think I understand everything after that

Comment: By the way, trying to get to a point where I can tell if it is a tautology, contradiction or contingency. I'm not trying to get back to the original question

Comment: In your booklet about logical rules, the *Rule of Syllogism* is **wrong**. From $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow C$ you cannot conclude $C$, but $A \rightarrow C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: though the other answers looked good, I tried in this one to use only the rules given in the notes referred to in a comment by the OP.

From your correct steps you have
$$\left((p\wedge\lnot z)\vee(\lnot p\wedge\lnot q)\right)\vee(z\vee q).$$
By using the commutative and associative laws (from the page you refer to) this can be rearranged to get
$$((p\wedge\lnot z)\vee z )\vee ((\lnot p\wedge\lnot q)\vee q).$$
Now the distributive laws may be applied in each half of the main $\vee.$ Technically they are written as distribution of a left term over two right ones, but with commutative laws there is no problem about that. We get to
$$((p \vee z) \wedge (\lnot z \vee z))\vee ((\lnot p \vee q) \wedge (\lnot q \vee q)).$$
Now in your notes it says one can use $A \vee \lnot A=T.$ Then by the identity law the two $T$ values may be dropped in the last line, and get to
$$(p \vee z) \vee (\lnot p \vee q).$$
From here we can bring the $p$ and $\lnot p$ together and get to $T \vee (z \vee q)$, and then by domination we arrive finally at $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from where you ended:

$\left((p\wedge\lnot z)\vee(\lnot p\wedge\lnot q)\right)\vee(z\vee q) \\
\lnot(\lnot p \vee z) \vee \lnot(p \vee q) \vee z \vee q \\
(\lnot(\lnot p \vee z) \vee z) \vee (\lnot(p \vee q) \vee q) \\
((\lnot p \vee z) \rightarrow z) \vee ((p\vee q) \rightarrow q) \\
((p \rightarrow z) \rightarrow z) \vee ((\lnot p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q)$

We know that either $p$ or $\lnot p$ is true.

Assume $p$ is true. Then $(p\rightarrow z) \rightarrow z$ simplifies to $z \rightarrow z$, which is tautologically true.

Assume $\lnot p$ is true. Then $(\lnot p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q$ simplifies to $q \rightarrow q$, which is tautologically true.

Thus the entire statement is equivalent to a tautology since it is always true.

Comment: This style of reasoning can be done even quicker: assume $\;p\;$ is true, then the original statement quickly simplifies to $\;z \rightarrow (z \lor q)\;$ which is a tautology; assume $\;p\;$ is false, then the original statement simplifies to $\;q \rightarrow (z \lor q)\;$, which also is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tautology.  We can prove it algebraically (using the Boolean logic rules).

First, let's apply distributivity to the antecedent:
$$(\neg p\vee z) \wedge (p\vee q) \equiv ((\neg p \vee z) \wedge p ) \vee ((\neg p \vee z) \wedge q).$$

Using distributivity again:
$$(\neg p \vee z) \wedge p ) \equiv (\neg p \wedge p) \vee (z \wedge p)$$
and then the identity rule:
$$(\neg p \wedge p) \vee (z \wedge p) \equiv (z\wedge p).$$

Now, the antecedent can be rewritten like this:
$$ (z\wedge p)\vee ((\neg p \vee z) \wedge q).$$

Again, we apply distributivity, to get:
$$ (z\wedge p)\vee ((\neg p \vee z) \wedge q)\equiv ( (z\wedge p)\vee(\neg p \vee z)) \wedge ( (z\wedge p)\vee q)$$
and again: 
$$( (z\wedge p)\vee(\neg p \vee z)) \wedge ( (z\wedge p)\vee q) \equiv ( ((z\wedge p)\vee \neg p) \vee ((z\wedge p)\vee z)) \wedge ( (z\wedge p)\vee q).$$

I'm going to skip the next few applications of distributivity, but you should be able to conclude:
\begin{eqnarray}
((z\wedge p) \vee \neg p) & \equiv & (z\vee \neg p) \\
((z\wedge p)\vee z)) & \equiv & z \\
((z\wedge p)\vee \neg p) \vee ((z\wedge p)\vee z) & = & (z\vee \neg p) \\
\end{eqnarray}

Then you just keep on in this vein.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in terms of the rules that you linked, but it might be nice to see this in a natural deduction form, too.  Since the formula is provable, it's a theorem (and thus a tautology).

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{|l}
(\lnot p \lor z) \land (p \lor q) \hspace{1cm}\mbox{Assume} \\
\hline 
\lnot p \lor z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\land$ elimination} \\
p \lor q \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\land$ elimination}\\
\begin{array}{|l}
p \hspace{1cm}\mbox{Assume}\\
\hline
\begin{array}{|l}
\lnot p \hspace{1cm}\mbox{Assume}\\
\hline
\bot \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\bot$ introduction}\\
z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\bot$ elimination}
\end{array} \\
\begin{array}{|l}
z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{Assume} \\ \hline z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{Reiteration}
\end{array} \\
z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\lor$ elimination} \\
q \lor z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\lor$ introduction}
\end{array} \\
\begin{array}{|l}
q \hspace{1cm}\mbox{Assume} \\ \hline q \lor z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\lor$ introduction} 
\end{array} \\
q \lor z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\lor$ elimination} 
\end{array} \\
((\lnot p \lor z) \land (p \lor q)) \to q \lor z \hspace{1cm}\mbox{$\to$ introduction}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The formula

> $((\lnot p \lor z) \land (p \lor q)) \rightarrow (z \lor q)$

is a "convoluted" version of :

> $((\lnot q \rightarrow p) \land (p \rightarrow z )) \rightarrow (\lnot q \rightarrow z)$

that is a *tautology*, being a version of [Hypothetical syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism).

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way to do this, a bit similar to [this earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/656781/11994).

Let's use the rules of (classical propositional) logic to simplify the statement, as follows:
\begin{align}
& (\lnot p \lor z) \land (p \lor q) \rightarrow (z \lor q) \\
= & \qquad \text{"rewrite $\;P \rightarrow Q\;$ to $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$ -- this gives more freedom to manipulate"} \\
& \lnot ((\lnot p \lor z) \land (p \lor q)) \lor z \lor q \\
= & \qquad \text{"DeMorgan (three times) and double negation -- to simplify"} \\
& (p \land \lnot z) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor z \lor q \\
= & \qquad \text{"use negation of $\;z\;$ on other side of $\;\lor\;$, and the same for $\;q\;$"} \\
& (p \land \lnot \text{false}) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot \text{false}) \lor z \lor q \\
= & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& p \lor \lnot p \lor z \lor q \\
= & \qquad \text{"excluded middle"} \\
& \text{true} \lor z \lor q \\
= & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& \text{true} \\
\end{align}
In other words, the original statement is a tautology.